# Unable to access bean package class from controller package class

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Using request dispatcher I am forwarding request from Servlet class which is in controller package to a class which is in bean package.Here is my code..

```
private void credentialProcessing(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

        try{


            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("algo");//this class is in bean package
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
         catch (ServletException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

[image: Screen shot of project]

Error:
when ever i try to do this Tomcat gives me error that requested resource not found ..on the other hand if i access control package class it is accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RequestDispatcher` uses paths to forward requests, it does not allow you to specify a class to forward to which the request is forwarded.

**getRequestDispatcher**

> Returns a RequestDispatcher object that acts as a wrapper for the
>   resource located at the given path. A RequestDispatcher object can be
>   used to forward a request to the resource or to include the resource
>   in a response. The resource can be dynamic or static.

If you want to access the `algo` class from the servlet create an instance of the class within the servlet.

```
private void credentialProcessing(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

        try{
           algo al = new algo();
           al.callSomeMethod();
        }
         catch (ServletException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**On a side note**

Look into the naming conventions for Java classes, which calls for class names to be uppercased.

Comment: @james I should have said paths.  What I mean by paths is the mapping of a url to a resource (servlet,jsp) in your project.  So for example if you create a servlet mapping of `/myServlet` the path to the servlet is ~domain/root/myServlet`.  This causes request directed to that path to be handled my the servlet.  RequestDispatcher works in the same manner.  When you use request dispatcher your basically submitting another request with a url that is used to find the appropriate resource.

Answer (score 1):

**Algo is a bean class I guess not a controller**, using rd.forward to forward requests does not mean that request can be forwarded from controller to bean class.

What you are doing as per code is like forwarding a request from one url to another.

If you want to forward the whole request simple instantiate algo class, and call some method which takes request as input param.

*In some controller method*

```
algo algoObj = new algo();
algo.processRequest (request, response);
```

Comment: +1 and Thanks for reply..both responses were same i will have to accept the one which came first.

Comment: No probs, glad you got the solution.